# cmake add prefix to linker

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, cmake, bullseye

I know how to add a prefix to linker. I need this because I need to add bullseye compiler and linker prefixes before compiling and linking.

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${BULLSEYE_PREFIX_CC} --no-banner ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${BULLSEYE_PREFIX_CC} --no-banner ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
```

I cant seem to find similar ones for linker. Any pointers?

Thanks,
Nick

These are the values to my compiler and linker prefixes. The compiler works fine and generates the cov file. However, the linker does not seem to be generating the executable. It compiles files and build executable but then it says its linking and fails. Not sure whats happening :(

```
C:/src/sw/tools/Bullseye/win32/8.7.33/BullseyeCoverage/bin/covc.exe C:/src/sw/to
ols/win32/msvc110/VC/bin/cl.exe
C:/src/sw/tools/Bullseye/win32/8.7.33/BullseyeCoverage/bin/covlink.exe <CMAKE_CO
MMAND> -E vs_link_exe <CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> /nologo <OBJECTS> @<<
 <FLAGS> /Fe<TARGET> /Fd<TARGET_PDB> -link /implib:<TARGET_IMPLIB> /version:<TAR
GET_VERSION_MAJOR>.<TARGET_VERSION_MINOR> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <L
INK_LIBRARIES>
<<
```

Comment: I m guessing its something to do with manifest. Anyone with VS knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINK_EXECUTABLE.html):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "${BULLSEYE_PREFIX_CC} ${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE}")
```

Note that it's not just path to linker but also flags and variables, e.g. for cygwin `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` is:

```
<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>  -o <TARGET> -Wl,--out-implib,<TARGET_IMPLIB> -Wl,--major-image-version,<TARGET_VERSION_MAJOR>,--minor-image-version,<TARGET_VERSION_MINOR> <LINK_LIBRARIES>
```

#### Note

This will add prefix but you should use caution. I would suggest to print using [message](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/message.html) command and see that the result is what you want. This variable is not easily customizable, so you might have to do some string processing in cmake.

Comment: OK I tried it. The linker wont build an executable. It compiles all files fine but it doesnt produce an executable. Not sure if its the compiler or linker problem. Must be linker. It says linking the executable but doesnt really generate any executable. Weird..